# Ignoring formulas in data validation

Tags: excel, validation, duplicates, formula

I am looking for a formula that would perform the following functions within data validation

> Check for duplicate numbers

> Ignore checking for duplicate if cell B2 (for example) contains the word "Continued".

To give explanation of what it is for, I have a logbook that my personnel puts in each call we are dispatched out to. They are labeled 22-0001, 22-0002, 22-0003, etc. Sometimes my personnel mistypes and adds a call number already created and we end up with 22-0001, 22-0002, 22-0002, 22-0003. This ends up throwing off our reports for the state and our numbers are then off from what our dispatch shows. This is where it then gets tricky. There is one exception for when a duplicate call number is allowed, and that is when they select "Continued" as the call type. We have this selection for if we have more units responding than can fit in one log form. We want to be able to put the same call number so we know which call the "Continued" is referring to, in case we need to backtrack in logs.

I figured out how to check for duplicates, my only issue is getting the formula to be ignored if the cell contains the text stated above.

Here is a screenshot of how the logbook is set up for reference. The red refers to the cell they input the call number, and the cell I want to prevent them from being able to type duplicates. And the orange is the cell I would like the function to refer to in order to see if the nature "Continued" is selected. If it is selected, I would like the first function preventing duplicate input to be ignored since it would still be part of the same call number.

[image: LogBookSet]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a helper column (see screenshot column duplicate) and then add conditional formatting. Or you use the formula within your conditional formatting.

Formula first counts all occurences of the callnumber of the current row within the first column - but only if type <> "continued".
(As there are two conditions, you need `countifs`.

If it occurs more than once an X is placed in the helper column.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS([callnumber];[@callnumber];[type];"<>continued")>1;"X";"")
```

If you don't use a table, then you have to replace [callnumber] by the column where you have your numbers. [@callnumber] refers to the special number of the current row.

[image]

Comment: Would this work for cells that aren't lined up? I realized I didn't add a screenshot of the logbook for reference so I updated my question to include the screenshot. I didn't create the logbook but this is what my department wants to use, so I am basically having to rework it as is to perform what I'm looking for it to do.

Comment: Ok - then it is a lot more complicated to identify the call numbers - especially if other numbers are entered in column B like the date ...

Comment: Yeah haha. Furthest I got was it being able to not allow them to duplicate the call number through data validation. It'll pop up telling them it is a duplicate number, requiring them to put in a different number. I may have to just have them put the call number next to "Continued" so we know that set refers to that call number. 
Personally I don't see a need to have the call number on the calls that have "continued" as the nature because the call it refers to is literally the set right above it. But it's how the Assistant Chief wants it so kinda stuck there.